# Remove first N characters of every line in Microsoft Word

Tags: text, ms-word

I have data in conversation format downloaded from WhatsApp. I have opened the data in MS Word and I want to remove the timestamps which appear on each line before each conversation

```
[16/02/20, 2:52:20 PM] Ron: Hello there 
[17/02/20, 2:53:21 PM] Harry:Hi Ron.
```

I want to remove the timestamp from each line. I am using a Macbook. Is there a way to take this to another notepad app and do the same, if not on MS word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with with a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = \[[!\[]@\]^32
Replace = nothing
```

No VBA code required.

Comment: the 32 is the number of characters? and nothing is just blank space?

Comment: ^32 represents the ASCII value of an ordinary space - if I'd simply have typed one there, you wouldn't have seen it.

Comment: Im on the mac, and when i try find = \[[!\[]@\]^32, I get "The Find What text for a Find All Word Forms search can only contain alphabetic letters." Am i missing out on something ?

Comment: Update: Found it in the wild cards section. You can post that as an answer! Another article outlines this for those wanting to understand in detail https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2018/07/22/word-wildcard-find-and-replace-for-numbers-inside-parentheses/

Comment: «Found it in the wild cards section. You can post that as an answer!» I already did that - I said to use *wildcards* from the outset, not *all word forms*.